# Execution of several conditions in CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains the fields: name, contract start date, contract end date

```
name       date_start      date_end

Helen      01.01.2018      01.08.2018

Peter      02.03.2018      03.04.2018

George     01.01.2018      06.08.2019

Lisa       03.04.2018      08.05.2018

Ann        01.03.2018      07.06.2018
```

I need to see who had contracts in effect at the beginning of each month of 2018. I also need a column with the start date of each month.

my code:

```
select 
name, date_start, date_end,
case 
    when date_start <= to_date('01.01.2018' ,'dd.mm.rrrr') and date_end >= to_date ('01.01.2018' ,'dd.mm.rrrr') then to_date ('01.01.2018' ,'dd.mm.rrrr')

   when date_start <= to_date('01.02.2018' ,'dd.mm.rrrr') and date_end >= to_date ('01.02.2018' ,'dd.mm.rrrr') then to_date ('01.02.2018' ,'dd.mm.rrrr')
.
.
.
   when date_start <= to_date('01.12.2018' ,'dd.mm.rrrr') and date_end >= to_date ('01.12.2018'        ,'dd.mm.rrrr') then to_date ('01.12.2018' ,'dd.mm.rrrr')

end  period
```

result of the code execution:

```
name    date_start      date_end        period
George  01.01.18    06.08.19    01.01.18
Peter   02.03.18    03.04.18    01.04.18
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.01.18
Lisa    03.04.18    08.05.18    01.05.18
Ann 01.03.18    07.06.18    01.03.18
```

WHAT I need:
For example, for Helen the contract is valid from January to August
I expect:

```
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.01.18
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.02.18
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.03.18
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.04.18
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.05.18
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.06.18
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.07.18
Helen   01.01.18    01.08.18    01.08.18
```

also for other names.
i know that case returns the result of the first expression  when expression that evaluates to TRUE.

But how can I realize what I'm expecting?

I work in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a calendar with 12 rows to cover the twelve months in 2018. Then join back to your data:

```
SELECT dates.month_start_date,
       mytable.*
  FROM (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),LEVEL-1) month_start_date
          FROM dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) dates,
       mytable
 WHERE dates.month_start_date BETWEEN mytable.date_start AND mytable.date_end
```